# DotNet command for building and generating zip file on mac machine

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone help me with the .net command for building and generating zip file.

I am trying to run below command on mac machine.

```
dotnet build ManageWebAppSourceControl.csproj /nologo /p:PublishProfile=Release /p:PackageLocation="" /p:OutDir="./package/bin" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /maxcpucount:1 /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="./package/package.zip"
```

It is building and generating the dlls under package folder but it's not generating the zip file.

Comment: Try specifying an actual `PackageLocation`, like `/p:PackageLocation="."` or a full path `/p:PackageLocation="/path/to/output"`

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I am using this app. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-dotnet-configure-deployment-sources-for-web-apps.                                                                                                 I am using this command: dotnet build ManageWebAppSourceControl.csproj /nologo /p:PublishProfile=Release /p:PackageLocation="." /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /maxcpucount:1 /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="package.zip"      It builds but doesn't create zip file.